# ZFC and Con(MK)

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, incompleteness

ZFC is a common axiomatic system, and so is MK. The latter is significantly stronger since it can deal with proper classes.

**Definition**: A cardinal $\kappa$ is inaccessible if it is regular and the regular cardinals less than it are unbounded in it.

**Theorem**: For any inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, $(V_\kappa, \in) \vDash \text{ZFC}$, and $(V_\kappa, V_{\kappa+1}, \in) \vDash \text{MK}$.

Because of this theorem, I was wondering which of the following theories is stronger:

- $\text{ZFC}$ augmented by the axiom "there exists an inaccessible cardinal" (I denote this $\text{ZFCi}$).
- $\text{ZFC}$ augmented by the axiom "MK set theory is consistent" (I denote this $\text{ZFCK}$).

In other words, I was wondering which of the following, if any, holds:

- $\text{ZFCi} \vDash \text{Con(ZFCK)}$
- $\text{ZFCK} \vDash \text{Con(ZFCi)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathsf{ZFCi}$ proves that there is a $\kappa$ such that $(V_{\kappa+1},V_\kappa,\in)\models\mathsf{MK}$. Consequently, $\mathsf{ZFCi}\vdash \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{MK})$, which in turn means that $\mathsf{ZFCi}\vdash$ "Every $\omega$-model satisfies $\mathsf{Con(MK)}$" since consistency is arithmetical. Since $V_\kappa$ is an $\omega$-model, this means $\mathsf{ZFCi}\vdash \exists \kappa((V_\kappa,\in)\models\mathsf{ZFCK})$.

Godel's second incompleteness theorem then tells us that $\mathsf{ZFCK}\not\vdash\mathsf{Con(ZFCi)}$.